# How to get the inserted path of a file in django?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have written a form which contains a filefield.
Now in my views I want to access the path of file which i inserted using this field....Is it possible and is yes what is the method, which can be used for the same??

Answer (score 2):

There are three (main) properties that [`File`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/files/#using-files-in-models) fields have in django:

`.name` = the file name

`.path` = file's location on the disk

`.url` = the URL to that file, which a browser can use. Use this when you want to provide a link to a file in the template.

Answer (score 0):

In Django files are represented by the [File](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/files/file/#the-file-class) class. This class has a field named `name`. The documentation for this field says:

> The name of file including the relative path from MEDIA_ROOT.

**Example**

Your MEDIA_ROOT is `media` and the name of your file is `my-test-file`.
Then `myfile.name` would return `media/my-test-file`.

Feel free to ask further questions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this gives me the path where in Django my file is..what I'm looking for is the location i gave in FILEFIELD because then I'll use it to run a script for moving that file

Comment: You'll have a copy of the file in your form and you can move this file. Or do you really really have to move the file your user selected? Your Django app would have to have direct access to the users machine. That's rareley the case.

Comment: Isn't this possible to get the original path from where the file was uploaded in django??